# How to plotting aggregated data in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, kibana

How do i plot in kibana the data that is returned from an aggregate query in elastic search.
I have tried the existing methods but could not achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Kibana does not currently have a way to display output of an [aggregate request](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1249) according to the bug tracker on github.  It looks like maybe it's coming in 4.0.